# Rename {mathmode} to {math-mode}

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tagging, badges

The common spelling of *math_mode* seems to be with a space in between the words: There are [109 questions with *math mode* in their title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=title:%22math%20mode%22), but only [17 with *mathmode*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=title:mathmode). Herbert Voß's paper [*Math mode*](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf) spells it with two words, too. Hence, I suggest [mathmode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathmode) be normalized to [math-mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math-mode), just like we have [table-of-contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/table-of-contents), [horizontal-alignment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horizontal-alignment) and [document-classes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/document-classes).

As I don't use LaTeX for math, I hope I'm not missing some environment or the like that actually spells `mathmode`; in that case, this suggestion would be void, of course.

I'm expecting the [18 {mathmode} bronze tag badges](https://tex.stackexchange.com/badges/65/mathmode), egreg's and Werner's [silver {mathmode} tag badges](https://tex.stackexchange.com/badges/118/mathmode) and egreg's [gold {mathmode} tag badge](https://tex.stackexchange.com/badges/181/mathmode) to be revoked by the system and new tag badges for [math-mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math-mode) to be awarded pretty much immediately, in the spirit of the meta.so question [What happens to a tag badge when a tag is merged with another one, or it is deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87506/what-happens-to-a-tag-badge-when-a-tag-is-merged-with-another-one-or-it-is-dele). The only thing that gets lost is the precise dates and order in which these badges were awarded, but I wouldn't regard this as a big problem. (I'd guess the new badges will be awarded in ascending order by user ID.)

---

Edit: Numbers updated + It might be possible for an admin to simply rename the tag and its badges so that the badges aren't revoked but just renamed, and no information is lost. It would be great if a moderator here could check this with SE.

> I have asked about this in the mod chat room: no answer. So if we want to go for this we will have to 'suck it and see' badge-wise. – [Joseph Wright](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2096/rename-mathmode-to-math-mode#comment6283_2096)

---

Addendum: The less frequent tag [textmode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/textmode) should similarly be renamed to [text-mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-mode), of course.

Comment: If the "old" badge is revoked -- and there's still a chance that the SO software treats "alternative routing" to a synonym more benign --, there's another information that would get diluted: The sequence of badge awards for individual users ("{mathmode} was my first tag badge").

Comment: @lockstep: Yes, so it's the order of each user's badges and the order of all the badge's recipients. Still, I'd consider this but a small sacrifice. The many users who'll receive the badge in the future will have the correct name _and_ the correct order.

Comment: BTW, I wrote "small chance [for benign behaviour]" above because my favouriting of the {index} tag was automatically redirected to {indexing}.

Comment: I'd be interested in the counter-arguments that led to the downvote, and in general in why people seem to be hesitant about this proposal.

Comment: Can't this be brought up on [Meta.SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com) by one of the mods or requested via email to StackExchange directly? Of course, if shown to be in favour of the change. By the way, I agree with your suggestion.

Comment: Update: it's a gold badge, now. :) I've nothing against the proposal, provided… :)

Comment: @egreg: I hadn't even seen that one yet, congrats! (Added)

Comment: @doncherry strangely, "modes" in tex seem to be one-word in many cases: `batchmode`, `nonstopmode`, ...; the commands `\ifmmode`, `\leavevmode` (I know, `\tableofcontents` is a counter-example to the last two, but still...) In my opinion, _tag synonym_ is the clear solution.

Comment: @tohecz: I'm not quite sure I understand what your point is and how `\tableofcontents` is a counterexample of `\leavemode`. TeX keywords don't contain spaces or hyphens, yes, but our tags do.

Comment: Sorry, I messed it completely. I meant: the command is `\tableofcontents` but the tag is [tag:table-of-contents]. Considering this I agree that the tag can be [tag:math-mode], even thought the corresponding command `\ifmmode` (and maybe others too) have no seperators. Still, [tag:mathmode] always seemed to me somehow natural...

Comment: @tohecz: Thanks for clarifying. Well, I don't think there are any commands containing separators as such, are there?

Comment: No, there aren't. And that is the reason why I don't mind {mathmode} at all...

Comment: I have asked about this in the mod chat room: no answer. So if we want to go for this we will have to 'suck it and see' badge-wise.

Comment: As there are 12 up- (me too) and only two down-votes, would you consider changing its tag from "discussion" to "feature-request"?

Comment: @JosephWright: Alright, I don't think there'll be any further discussion or any new points; but the score is reasonably high -- let's suck it and see.

Comment: @JosephWright: Thanks. Could you also do the [tag:textmode] to [tag:text-mode] rename? There aren't any badges for that, so we're safe. I don't think we need a separate question for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it looks like the old [mathmode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathmode) badges have been revoked and new [math-mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math-mode) badges have been awarded; see e.g. [egreg's profile](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg?tab=badges), who interestingly even got his gold badge before the silver one, which again he got before the bronze one. Sorry about the lost date information.

<s>I think I'll put a question on meta.so to document this behavior, once the situation has stabilized. (Right now, the [badge list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/badges?tab=tags) still show [mathmode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathmode) badges, even though nobody has them anymore.)</s>

I put a feature request regarding the behavior of badges on renaming on meta.so: [Don't revoke and reaward tag badges when the tag is renamed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138854/162565)

Comment: The loss of date information is a bit of a nuisance, but I can survive it. :)