# Rename {textmode} to {text-mode}

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tagging

Just a small follow-up of [Rename {mathmode} to {math-mode}](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2096/4012). Don't worry, there aren't any badges for [textmode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/textmode) yet `;)`. The reasoning is once again that in regular writing the tag would be *text mode*, so the space should be translated into a hyphen in the "tagese" language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I renamed the tag, now its name is [text-mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-mode), similar to [math-mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math-mode), [dvi-mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dvi-mode), and [org-mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/org-mode), which we already have.